# Checked attribute of checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, icenium

I am writing a code for kendo UI mobile in which i want to show a particular div on check on of check box for this i am writing a function as follows

```
           function showDetails(){
              // debugger;
               var data = $("#vehicleLoan").attr('checked');
               // alert(data);
               if(data)
               {
                   $("#Loan").removeAttr("style","display:block");
               }
               else
               {
                   $("#Loan").removeAttr("style","display:none");   
               }
           }
```

but i am getting an undefined at data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using,

```
var data = $("#vehicleLoan").is(':checked');
```

OR

```
    function showDetails(){
               $("#Loan").toggle();
     }
```

OR

```
    function showDetails(){
          // debugger;
           var data = $("#vehicleLoan").is(':checked');
           // alert(data);
           if(data)
           {
               $("#Loan").show();
           }
           else
           {
               $("#Loan").hide();   
           }
       }
```

Comment: It is giving me False no matter it is checked or unchecked

Comment: Can you post your html part here ?

Comment: <li><label>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicleLoan"onchange="showDetails();"/>Vehicle Loan:<br>
</label></li>

Comment: </li>
<div id="Loan" style="display:none">
<li><label>Loan Period:<input type="text" id="loanPeriod"/>  </label></li>
<li><label>EMI Amount:<input type="text" id="EMIAmount"/></label>
</li>        
<li>
                                       <label>
                                        EMI Date:
                                        <input type="text" id="insuranceTo"/>       
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                        <li>

Comment: please consider both comments for HTML

Comment: Ok sure, giveme some time i will check and update you

Comment: Updated answer please check, provided two methods

Comment: but it is just showing me my div properly, there are three text boxes in div tag which is not visible when actual div is visible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41930/discussion-between-trupti-and-user876345)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   if(document.getElementById("vehicleLoan").checked)
   {
       $("#Loan").removeAttr("style","display:block");
   }
   else
   {
       $("#Loan").removeAttr("style","display:none");   
   }
```